# Does odata 4 support group by ENUM?

Tags: asp.net-core, odata

We have an aspnet core site running Odata v4.
I have enabled Odata routes like so.

```
app.UseMvc(routeBuilder =>
        {
            routeBuilder.MapODataServiceRoute("odata", $"{serviceName}/1.0", model);
            //routeBuilder.EnableDependencyInjection();
            routeBuilder.EnableDependencyInjection(builder =>
            {
                builder.AddService(Microsoft.OData.ServiceLifetime.Singleton, typeof(ODataUriResolver), sp => new StringAsEnumResolver());
            });
        });
```

I can filter by the ENUM value on my model, but I dont seem to be able to groupby?

is this supported?